# Is there a way to set multiple defaults on a Python dict using another dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I've got two dicts in Python:

```
mydict = { 'a': 0 }

defaults = {
    'a': 5,
    'b': 10,
    'c': 15
}
```

I want to be able to expand `mydict` using the default values from `defaults`, such that 'a' remains the same but 'b' and 'c' are filled in.  I know about [`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) and [`dict.update()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update), but each only do half of what I want - with `dict.setdefault()`, I have to loop over each variable in `defaults`; but with `dict.update()`, `defaults` will blow away any pre-existing values in `mydict`.

Is there some functionality I'm not finding built into Python that can do this?  And if not, is there a more Pythonic way of writing a loop to repeatedly call `dict.setdefaults()` than this:

```
for key in defaults.keys():
    mydict.setdefault(key, defaults[key])
```

Context: I'm writing up some data in Python that controls how to parse an XML tree.  There's a dict for each node (i.e., how to process each node), and I'd rather the data I write up be sparse, but filled in with defaults.  The example code is just an example...  real code has many more key/value pairs in the default dict.

(I realize this whole question is but a minor quibble, but it's been bothering me, so I was wondering if there was a better way to do this that I am not aware of.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couldnt you make mydict be a copy of default, That way, mydict would have all the correct values to start with?

```
mydict = default.copy()
```

Comment: I thought about this, but wouldn't copying the entire defaults be pretty inefficient (especially mydict has all values set to begin with)?  You'd be creating a new dict, copying all the values out of another one, then rewriting the whole dict again in that case.

Comment: @Daniel Lew: the values won't be copied, just references to them. The new dict will have new references to the same values in memory.

Comment: You can test it for speed - it is certainly less code and more elegant in that it is immediately clear what you are trying to do. I think that it might be faster than your method if for no other reason than it is all happening inside the interpreter and is likely fairly optimized.

Answer (score 8):

Since Python 3.9, you can do:

```py
mydict = defaults | mydict
```

I found this solution to be the most elegant in my usecase.

Comment: Cool solution. You can also do `mydict = mydict | (defaults | mydict)` if you need to maintain the original key order.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind creating a new dictionary in the process, this will do the trick:

```
newdict = dict(defaults)
newdict.update(mydict)
```

Now `newdict` contains what you need.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this the same way Python's `collections.DefaultDict` works:

```
class MultiDefaultDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, defaults, **kwargs):
        self.defaults = defaults
        self.update(kwargs)
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.defaults[key]

>>> mydict2 = MultiDefaultDict(defaults, a=0)
>>> mydict2['a']
0
>>> mydict2['b']
10
>>> mydict2
{'a': 0}
```

The other solutions posted so far duplicate all the default values; this one shares them, as requested. You may or may not want to override other dict methods like `__contains__()`, `__iter__()`, `items()`, `keys()`, `values()` -- this class as defined here iterates over the non-default items only.

Comment: +1 It's also worth emphasizing that unlike `defaultdict` (and `setdefault()`) any missing keys and associated default values are *not* actually added to the underlying dictionary -- which may or may not be desirable. In any case that, of course, could be changed...

Answer (score 0):

```
defaults.update(mydict)
```

Comment: Then how will I be able to apply my defaults to another node?

Comment: keep a copy of original somewhere.

Comment: defaults IS the original.  :P

Comment: well after you update it it won't be. and you might as well add this new info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like to append the dictionary object. It works mostly like a dictionary except that you have to create the object first.

```
class d_dict(dict):
    'Dictionary object with easy defaults.'
    def __init__(self,defaults={}):
        self.setdefault(defaults)           
    def setdefault(self,defaults):
        for key, value in defaults.iteritems():
            if not key in self:
                dict.__setitem__(self,key,value)
```

This provides the exact same functionality as the dict type except that it overrides the setdefault() method and will take a dictionary containing one or more items. You can set the defaults at creation.

This is just a personal preference. As I understand all that dict.setdefault() does is set the items which haven't been set yet. So probably the simplest in place option is:

```
new_dict = default_dict.copy()
new_dict.update({'a':0})
```

However, if you do this more than once you might make a function out of this. At this point it may just be easier to use a custom dict object, rather than constantly adding defaults to your dictionaries.