# Initialize Python variable from possible missing dict value

Tags: python, dictionary, initialization, indexing

What is the Pythonic way to do this?

```
value = (mydict.has_key('index') and mydict['index']) or 1024
```

Initialize from a dict's value, if present, otherwise use default value.

Got some answers on LBYL and EAFP, but too verbose code :p

I want some one-line-initialize.

PS: python-2.4 only (running CentOS5)

Comment: Actually your code does this: "Initialize from a dict's value, if present and *not considered a boolean False value*, otherwise use default value."

Comment: Right! Forgot to say that 'index' is never boolean (code constraint) Sorry.

Comment: Doesn't matter if they're actually a boolean type because in Python a number of things such as `None`, `()`, `[]`, `''`, `{}`, `0`, and `0.0` are considered `False` if used in a logical expression -- what some have called their intrinsic "[truthiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness)".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
value = mydict.get('index', 1024)
```

(Note that this is not exactly equivalent to your code, since it will use `1024` only if the key `index` is not present, while your code also uses `1024` when the value corresponding to key `index` is falsy.  From your explanation I infer the former is what you actually want.)

Comment: It is critically important to note that, because python is a non-lazy language, the "default value" expression will be evaluated whether or not you actually end up using it. (In contrast to an `if` statement which will not evaluate it.)

Comment: @ninjagecko is right - if the default value is expensive to construct and you care about performance you'll want to avoid using `get`/`setdefault`. I often use a `try: ... except KeyError:` idiom in this case, especially if I expect the key 'misses' to be rare.

Comment: @ninjagecko, Whatang: `value = mydict['index'] if 'index' in mydict else 1234` is the lazy oneliner. I just want to make it clear that it does not matters here, because 1234 is extremely cheap to create.

Comment: if the default value is expensive and the value from the dict will be non-falsey then you can do `value = mydict.get('index') or doexpensiveoperation()` which is not as nice but still pretty short.

Comment: @lambacck: This will give an unexpected result if `index` is in the dictionary, but its assigned value is falsy.

Comment: How about this: dict={1:None}. In this case, dict.get(1) yelds to None.

Comment: @Sven: which is why I prefixed the statement with "and the value from the dict will be non-falsey" Sometimes you know that you will *always* have a non-falsey value.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use `setdefault()` - like `get()`, but it inserts the key before returning the value:

```
value = mydict.setdefault('index', 1024)
```

Comment: It is critically important to note that, because python is a non-lazy language, the "default value" expression will be evaluated whether or not you actually end up using it. (In contrast to an `if` statement which will not evaluate it.)

Answer (score 1):

The `get` and `setdefault` methods are important to know, they should be in any Python programmer's toolbox.

Another important way of doing this  is to use `collections.defaultdict`, because then you can define your "default" in a single place without having to scatter it throughout your code wherever the dictionary is used, i.e. Don't Repeat Yourself. Then if you change the default you don't need to hunt through your code finding all those gets and setdefaults. For example

```
>>> import collections
>>> myDict = collections.defaultdict
>>> myDict = collections.defaultdict(lambda : 1024)
>>> myDict[0] += 1
>>> print myDict[0], myDict[100]
1025 1024
```

Because you get to set the function call, you can do whatever you like for your default value. How about assigning a random value between 1 and 10 for every new key?

```
>>> import collections
>>> import random
>>> myDict = collections.defaultdict(lambda : random.randint(1,10))
>>> print myDict[0], myDict[100]
1 5
>>> print myDict[0], myDict[100], myDict[2]
1 5 6
```

OK, that example's a little contrived, but I'm sure you can think of better uses. Say you have an expensive class to construct - the instance is only created if the key is not actually present, unlike when calling `get` and `setdefault`, e.g.

```
>>> class ExpensiveClass(object):
>>>     numObjects = 0
>>>     def __init__(self):
>>>         ExpensiveClass.numObjects += 1
>>> 
>>> print ExpensiveClass.numObjects
0
>>> x = {}
>>> x[0] = ExpensiveClass()
>>> print ExpensiveClass.numObjects
1
>>> print x.get(0, ExpensiveClass())
<__main__.ExpensiveClass object at 0x025665B0>
>>> print ExpensiveClass.numObjects
2
>>> ExpensiveClass.numObjects = 0
>>> z = collections.defaultdict(ExpensiveClass)
>>> print ExpensiveClass.numObjects
0
>>> print z[0]
>>> <__main__.ExpensiveClass object at 0x02566510>
>>> print ExpensiveClass.numObjects
1
```

Note that the call to `x.get` constructs a new `ExpensiveClass` instance, even though we don't ever use that instance because `x[0]` already exists. This could cause problems if you were indeed trying to count the number of `ExpensiveClass` objects, or if they were very slow to create. These problems don't occur for `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `setdefault()` and `defaultdict` both have the side-effect of adding any missing key to the dictionary. Also when using a `defaultdict` you may need more than a simple *default_factory* function if you want the default value to vary depending on the key (because the factory function is not passed the key being look-up).

Comment: One other things, `defaultdict` wasn't added until Python 2.5 (and the OP is using 2.4).

Comment: `defaultdict` seems amazing because it is lazy, so the lambda isn't evaluated unless it's needed; wish I could upvote more

Comment: @martineua oops, sorry missed the Python 2.4. And yes, absolutely, sometimes `defaultdict` can be a little limiting because you can't specify the key to the factory function.

Answer (score 1):

The `collections` module `defaultdict` class might be of help. Unfortunately it wasn't introduced until Python 2.5 and it doesn't do *exactly* what your code does. Here's a few differences:

- It only supplies a value when a key is missing, not when it is there but has a value considered `False`.
- If the looked-up key is missing it will add it to the dictionary with a default value as well as return the default value.
- All missing values get the same default value.

If that's OK you can emulate the essence of one in older Pythons with something like this:

```
try:
    from collections import defaultdict
except ImportError:
    class defaultdict(dict):
        def __init__(self, default_factory=None, *a, **kw):
            dict.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
            self.default_factory = default_factory

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            try:
                return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
            except KeyError:
                return self.__missing__(key)

        def __missing__(self, key):
            self[key] = value = self.default_factory()
            return value
```

A recipe for a more complete emulation is available on [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/523034/). Even if you had Python 2.5+, you might want to derive your own class to customize to have the exact behavior you wanted. Besides checking for "False" truth values and perhaps not adding any missing ones to the dictionary, you could also provide it with a separate dictionary of multiple default values corresponding to different keys instead of "one size fits all". For ways to do that see [*Is there a way to set multiple defaults on a Python dict using another dict?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849806/is-there-a-way-to-set-multiple-defaults-on-a-python-dict-using-another-dict/850402#850402).